# Programmatically Add add-in button to the standard toolbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, toolbar

I write simple add-in for visual studio. the add-in contains two command:

```
command1 = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "AAAA", "AAAA", "Executes the   command for MyAddin2" ,true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported+(int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
command2 = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "BBBB", "BBBB", "Executes the command for MyAddin2", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStyleText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
```

when I run the add-in, these two buttons apear under the Tools tab of Visual Studio.
I want them to be appear in the standard toolbar. manually, I can do that by Tools -> Customize -> Commands tab -> Add Command -> select addins and then choose my two buttons. can I do it programmatically?
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var cBar = Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars["Standard"];
var button = (CommandBarButton)cBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true);
button.Caption = "Test";
```